# Open .eml file with running thunderbird installed from snap

Tags: snap, thunderbird

I use thunderbird installed from snap in my ubuntu 22.04.

When TB is **not running** and I double click on an .eml file it opens it in a message window in thunderbird. As it should.

When thunderbird **is already running** it says:

> Thunderbird is already running, but is not responding. To use Thunderbird, you must first close the existing Thunderbird process, restart your device, or use a different profile.

The [help page from thunderbird regarding this topic](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_in_use#Remove_the_profile_lock_file) is not helpful for this.

When I open the .eml file without a running thunderbird it opens in the same and only profile I have. So it is not about not finding the profile. I guess it has something to do with the snap installation as it worked before.

Had anybody the same issue and a solution?